# How to color background of the same values in the whole table?

Tags: r

I wanted to use cell_spec function to obtain colour at the background of the same values across tibble. My dataset looks like that:

| name | F1 | F2 | F3 | F4 | F6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| name2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

So that background of all values with "1" will be one colour, background of all values with "2" will be second colour etc. (I have 6 values in dataset 1,2,3,4,5,6)

I used this code, but unfortunately it's returning the same dataframe, not colouring anything

```
result_tibble %>% kbl() %>% row_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>% cell_spec(1, background = "#FF0000") %>% cell_spec(2, background = "#FFA500") %>% cell_spec(3, background = "#FFFF00") %>% cell_spec(4, background = "#00FF00") %>% cell_spec(5, background = "#0000FF")
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `cell_spec()` function across the needed columns combined with a case_when:

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
df %>% 
  mutate(
    across(F1:F6, 
           ~ cell_spec(.x, 
                       background = case_when(.x == 1 ~ "#FF0000",
                                              .x == 2 ~ "#FFA500",
                                              .x == 3 ~ "#FFFF00",
                                              .x == 4 ~ "#00FF00", 
                                              .x == 5 ~ "#0000FF")
           )
    )
  ) %>% 
  kable(booktabs = T, linesep = "", format = "html", escape = F) %>% 
  kable_paper(full_width = F)
```

[image]